# Increase the width instead of overlap when using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build a sort of carousel effect. I am using flexbox to line the divs up. The design is made for a screen that has resolution 1920x1080 and all the divs line up properly but when I move it to a smaller screen the divs overlap. I want them to still be on one line but keep the same width of each div and scroll to reveal the overflow.

```css
.articleDisplay {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/*ARTICLE FLIPPING*/

.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 352px;
  height: 450px;
}
.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  background-image: url(http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg);
  width: 352px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #f8f9f9;
}
.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  width: 352px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #f8f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  color: #232022;
}
```

```html
<div class="articleDisplay">
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4 class="rating">Hello</h4>
        <div class="rating">
          <center>
            <p id="rate">4.3</p>
          </center>
        </div>
        <h5>This will be a headline</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription">I've got a pen</p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription">I've got an apple</p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription">UH</p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription">APPLE PEN</p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription"></p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've removed irrelevant CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two adjustments:

```
.articleDisplay {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;    /* NEW */
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
  min-width: 352px; /* ADJUSTED (formerly `width: 352px`) */
  height: 450px;
}
```

The first adjustment tells the container to enable a scrollbar when there is overflow.

The second adjustment prevents the divs from shrinking/overlapping by setting a minimum width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the flip-container to shrink on smaller viewports.

```
.flip-container { flex-shrink: 1; }
```

and then give the flipping tiles (front/back) a max-width of 100% instead of setting a fixed width..

```
.front, .back { max-width: 100%; }
```

See it in action below.

```css
.articleDisplay {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/*ARTICLE FLIPPING*/

.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  background-image: url(http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg);
  width: 352px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #f8f9f9;
}
.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  width: 352px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #f8f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  color: #232022;
}
```

```html
<div class="articleDisplay">
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4 class="rating">Hello</h4>
        <div class="rating">
          <center>
            <p id="rate">4.3</p>
          </center>
        </div>
        <h5>This will be a headline</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription">I've got a pen</p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription">I've got an apple</p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription">UH</p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription">APPLE PEN</p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <h4 class="articleHeader">#BR2017 NEW VENUE</h4>
        <p class="articleDescription"></p>
        <button class="readMore">
          CONTINUE READING
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this helps in one way but what I want is to put divs that don't fit with the already set size to be hidden outside the page so you can scroll to them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWBOjR)

You should be able to achieve what you want, simply by adding `max-width: 100%;` to your `.flip-container,
.front,
.back`